# Why Lodash _.isObject(null) is false while in javascript typeof null is 'object'?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I don't understand why Lodash's _.isObject() function depicts null to being of type object while in Javascript it actually is an object?

Why do they (lodash) do this on the function?

```
function isObject(value) {
  const type = typeof value
  return value != null && (type == 'object' || type == 'function')
}

export default isObject
```

Comment: because it's trying to useful instead of redundant.

Comment: Just because `typeof null` is `"object"` does not mean that `null` is *really* an object. It's a null object reference, but for practical purposes it is not an object.

Comment: That's more of a philosophical question than a practical one.